# Функция pg_query() "говорит": ошибка синтаксиса, а pg_result_error() выводит пустую строку, а чем может быть проблема?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, запрос, openserver

Пытаюсь загрузить данные в таблицу Postgres. Скрипт и данные находятся на локальном сервере Open Server, а бд на другом, удаленном серваке, к которому есть полный доступ (соединяюсь с базой через менеджер бд и все редактирую). Подключение к базе при запуске скрипта успешно происходит, но вот запрос INSERT INTO не срабатывает:

```
$pg = "INSERT INTO public.1253_data () VALUES " . implode(",", $temp_array);
```

Ошибка выдается от функции pg_query, пишет: Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: Ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: .1253_data).

Я запускаю функцию pg_result_query():

```
$result = pg_query($conn, $sql);


 if ($result) {
   echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
      $k = pg_get_result($result);
      echo 'Query failed1: ' . pg_result_error($k);
}
pg_close($conn);
```

В результате pg_result_error дает пустоту:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по документации, pg_result_дает такое только тогда, когда ошибок никаких нет. Но тогда почему собственный дескриптор ошибки pg_query такой?

Только начинаю pg изучать, все перепробовал в поисках ошибки ( Эксперты, подскажите, в чем она может быть?

Comment: `pg_last_error($conn);`

Comment: Добавил такой код:  echo 'Проверка подключения:' . pg_last_error($conn); Пишет то же самое: "Проверка подключения:ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: ".1253_data")

Comment: @u_mulder также попробовал так: var_dump($conn); такой результат дает: resource(5) of type (pgsql link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В результате pg_result_error дает пустоту

Как прямо указано в документации что [`pg_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php)

> If an error occurs, and false is returned, details of the error can be
> retrieved using the pg_last_error() function if the connection is
> valid.

Так и в описании [`pg_result_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-error.php) явно оговорено

> Because pg_query() returns false if the query fails, you must use pg_send_query() and pg_get_result() to get the result handle.

---

> Ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: .1253_data)

Поясните, чем именно вас не устраивает полученный текст ошибки. Вполне однозначное сообщение об ошибке, даже указывающее на проблемное место. Совершенно резонно указывающее на ошибку синтаксиса. Ведь [по синтаксису](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html) SQL идентификатор не может начинаться с цифры:

> SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also
> letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore
> (_). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be
> letters, underscores, digits (0-9), or dollar signs ($).

Если по какой-то мутной причине вы хотите именовать таблицу именно так - вы обязаны к ней обращаться, используя `quoted identifier` синтаксис. То есть,

```
INSERT INTO public."1253_data"
```

Но лучше лишний раз подумайте, зачем. Меня такой вид именования таблицы подводит к мысли, что 1253 - это какой-то внешний идентификатор из другой таблицы (id пользователя или что-то подобное) - то есть явная ошибка проектирования схемы базы данных.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Благодаря Вам удалось решить проблему!

Answer (score 0):

Неправильный синтаксис для INSERT используете. Скобки должны стоять вокруг значений:

```
insert into sometable values ('val1, 'val2');
```

Должно быть так:

```
$pg = "INSERT INTO public.1253_data VALUES " . implode(",", $temp_array);
```

и убедитесь, что у вас значения в `temp_array` соответствуют колонкам в таблице. Еще лучше колонки явно перечислить:

```
$pg = "INSERT INTO public.1253_data (column1, column2, column3, и т.д.) VALUES " . implode(",", $temp_array);
```

Comment: А у меня $temp_array - массив строк такого вида: "('" . $a . "', " . $b .  ")". То есть, у меня скобки в самом массиве. Извините, что сразу не уточнил эту деталь. Данные подставляются успешно, я это вижу в браузере... Потом, ранее данный скрипт использовался на сервере и сам синтаксис запроса отрабатывал. Тут в чем-то другом дело..

Comment: главное это то, что пустые скобки `()` перед `values` недопустимы. проблема в этом

Comment: Запустил без скобок совсем и со скобками и указанием столбцов - все равно тот же результат..(

Comment: Значит в дополнение к этой есть и еще какая-то проблема. Включите в вопрос полный текст запроса, который посылаете на выполнение.

Comment: Это и есть полный текст.. Остальное, это формирование массива, но с ним все ок, так как раньше в таком же виде информация загружалась.. В строки имплодится он тоже правильно.. Что делается впервые, так это закидывание из Open Server в таблицу бд удаленного сервера.. Ранее тем же скриптом информация вставлялась на том же сервере, на котором была работа..